# Isotope combine search and buttons with initial filter

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a page that let you search through categories and starts with a specific category on page load.

Started with this codepen:
http://codepen.io/desandro/pen/mCdbD

Now I have this: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MaYeMR

I have figured out how to load a specific category like this on page load by adding a default filter like this:

```
    filter: '.transition'
```

Also figured out how to sort categories with the buttons like this:

```
  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: buttonFilter });
  });
```

This works beautifully, however the search functionality seems to be broken. No results show up whenever I try to search something in the search field. I believe it has something to do with comparing the search value in this part:

```
  // use value of search field to filter
  var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $container.isotope({ filter: qsRegex });
```

Entire javascript:

```
$( function() {
  // quick search regex
  var qsRegex;
  var buttonFilter;

  // init Isotope
  var $container = $('.isotope').isotope({
    itemSelector: '.element-item',
    layoutMode: 'fitRows',
    filter: '.transition'
  });

  $('#filters').on( 'click', 'button', function() {
    buttonFilter = $( this ).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({ filter: buttonFilter });
  });

  // use value of search field to filter
  var $quicksearch = $('#quicksearch').keyup( debounce( function() {
    qsRegex = new RegExp( $quicksearch.val(), 'gi' );
    $container.isotope({ filter: qsRegex });
  }) );


    // change is-checked class on buttons
  $('.button-group').each( function( i, buttonGroup ) {
    var $buttonGroup = $( buttonGroup );
    $buttonGroup.on( 'click', 'button', function() {
      $buttonGroup.find('.is-checked').removeClass('is-checked');
      $( this ).addClass('is-checked');
    });
  });


});

// debounce so filtering doesn't happen every millisecond
function debounce( fn, threshold ) {
  var timeout;
  return function debounced() {
    if ( timeout ) {
      clearTimeout( timeout );
    }
    function delayed() {
      fn();
      timeout = null;
    }
    setTimeout( delayed, threshold || 100 );
  };
}
```

My first question here so I hope it's no too vague, tried explaining what steps I took and where I believe it went wrong. I couldn't find any related issues with combining the search functionality with a initial filter.

Comment: That first Codepen seems to work like a champ. Well done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know anything about Isotope, but from reviewing your code vs. the original, it seems like a better approach for what you want to do would be to keep the filter function from the original code and trigger it appropriately.

In order to do this for the initial filter, I added this code to the bottom of the initialization function:

```
// "click" the button of the initial filter
var initialFilter = '.transition';
if (initialFilter) {
    $('#filters .button[data-filter="' + initialFilter + '"]')
        .trigger('click');
}
```

You didn't specify how you intended to initialize the filter, so the `initialFilter` variable is there just to simulate the initial filter specification.

Here's the full code forked from the original: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WQboyG

Comment: I just want to start with a specific filter (.transition) on page load. Your example worked beautifully. Only thing I noticed was the difference in performance; the initial filter loads faster when it is loaded when Isotope is initialized. Marked as answered as your code solves my problem, thanks a lot!